# Data Sources for Revenues of European Football Clubs?

Tags: data-request, europe, football

Football industry revenue data. For instance, expense related data, accounts payroll, wage transfer data?

Comment: Where/what have you done to find/access this data?

Answer (score 1):

[Annual Review of Football Finance 2020](https://www2.deloitte.com/uk/en/pages/sports-business-group/articles/annual-review-of-football-finance.html)

The Deloitte Annual Review of Football Finance is produced by the Sports Business Group at Deloitte and is the most comprehensive review of the business and finances of English professional football, set within the context of the regulatory environment and the wider European game

---

[Association football](https://www.kaggle.com/tags/association-football)

---

[Market size of the European professional football market from 2006/07 to 2017/18](https://www.statista.com/statistics/261223/european-soccer-market-total-revenue/)

---

[There are 338 sports datasets available on data.world.](https://data.world/datasets/sports)

---

[Top-20 European soccer clubs by total revenue 2018/19 season](https://www.statista.com/statistics/271581/revenue-of-soccer-clubs-worldwide/)